# Redirect to URL before Execute JS Function in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

how to First Redirect to particular URL and after that execute function logic in JavaScript ?

i have try following code.
JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onHrefClick(varHref) {
        window.open(varHref, '_blank');
        //here code
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="onHrefClick('www.google.com')">Google</a>
```

But it always first execute my code and then it will redirect to URL.

**Update :**

i try this also it will open first popup window then redirect on page. it will wait for redirect till i am not click on Popup OK button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onHrefClick(varHref) {
    window.open(varHref, '_blank');
    alert(varHref);
}
```

**I want to redirect on external link so here no any parent or child concept**

Comment: But you are redirecting in that method so it will redirect and do whatever you wish after that

Comment: @Kabali if i added popup after window.open it will first open popup then redirect to that URL but i want first redirect to that URL and then open popup.

Comment: I think if you redirect first you can't execute the pages's code after.

Comment: @RicardoMota i try this is execute whole code and in last it will redirect on that link.

Comment: @MatiasCicero here not any child or parent concept i want to redirect it on external link like google.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```js
            function myFunction() {
                //my code here
                $('a').css('color', 'red');
            }
            function redirectOnHrefClick(varHref) {
                window.open(varHref, '_blank');
                myFunction();
            }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="redirectOnHrefClick('www.google.com')">Google</a>
```

This work. I tested here.
I hope to help.

Comment: but i want to first redirect on page and then execute code.

Comment: This case you need to insert the code in other page. I will edit my answer.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function after() {
            alert("Hello");
        }
        function onHrefClick(varHref) {
            window.open(varHref, '_blank');
            after();
        }
    </script>

i try this but it will first open popup and then redirect on URL.

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do ? Because I tried some codes here and they worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the page and execute the script in that page, there are 2 things that you can do:

1. If the webpage is controlled by you, please go ahead and write the code in $(Document).Ready(function() {} ) function.
2. If the website is controlled by a external source like www.google.com please go ahead and check if there is any api easing it.